# Android manifest merger file QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, which package uses it

Tags: android, react-native

How can I tell which react native npm package uses QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission?

My manifest-merger-debug-report menitions it here:

```
MERGED from [net.time4j:time4j-android:4.2-2018i] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0ee286b76ecfa7960380746552d7a51c/transformed/jetified-time4j-android-4.2-2018i/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-13:12
MERGED from [com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.2] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/18650036d482c03285034f37caa3af37/transformed/jetified-installreferrer-1.1.2/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-13:12
MERGED from [com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f4984a132f67c1e16eb1e7d0d95fa859/transformed/jetified-core-1.9.0/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-19:12
MERGED from [com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.1.3] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e0258fd5b39bb22740d611ac0ef34f66/transformed/jetified-conceal-1.1.3/AndroidManifest.xml:7:1-16:12
MERGED from [me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/36697fe461a4a658efbf19f809390a34/transformed/jetified-ShortcutBadger-1.1.22/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-52:12
MERGED from [com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:2.0.0] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a7d8e64b2305b52d0a7ca57d49561414/transformed/jetified-fbcore-2.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-9:12
MERGED from [androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7174d2cec5c177fadd1098a926b7b694/transformed/jetified-annotation-experimental-1.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:17:1-24:12
INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-13:12
INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-13:12
INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-13:12
    package
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-33
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-33
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    android:versionName
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:1:1-83:12
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    xmlns:tools
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-51
    android:versionCode
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:1:1-83:12
        INJECTED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    xmlns:android
```

mentioned here:

```
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:1:11-69
uses-permission#android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES
ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-77
    android:name
        ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5:22-74
uses-permission#android.permission.INTERNET
ADDED from /Users/user/apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-67
MERGED from [:react-native-maps] /Users/user/apps/myracnative/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-67
```

Comment: As per logs, your this is added from apps/myracnative/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
which is your Manifest file.

Comment: Which npm package is adding that to the manifest though?

Comment: You can use `grep -R QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES *` to get all the packages where this is being used